# Add UILabel on random position on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How do I Achieve Something like below image,

I want to add n number of `UILabel` to screen on random position without overlapping of label, and also randomly set rotate.

Here is my code, but it is overlapping label to another label:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var textDatas = ["aaa","bbb","cccccc","ddddddd","ee","ffffff","ggggg","hhhh","iiiiii","jjjjjj","kkkkkk","ll","mmmmm","nnnnnnnn","ooooooooo","ppppppppp","qqqqqqqqqqqq","rrrrrrrr","sssssss","ttttttttt","uuuuuuu","vvvv","wwww","xxxxxx","yyyy","zzzzzzz"]

    textDatas.forEach { (textData) in
        let randomIntX = Int.random(in: 10..<Int(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH-200))
        let randomIntY = Int.random(in: 50..<Int(ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT-50))
        let randomIntFontSize = Int.random(in: 10..<40)
        let randomIntLabelRotate = Int.random(in: 1..<3)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: randomIntX, y: randomIntY, width: 200, height: 30))
        label.font = UIFont(name: FONT_AVENIR_HEAVY,
                            size: CGFloat(randomIntFontSize))
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = textData
        label.sizeToFit()

        if randomIntLabelRotate == 1 {
            label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
        }

        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Is there any library or solution of this will be very appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Before adding to the screen, you should be checking if there is already a label placed in the coordinates the new label is about to be placed. Or at least check that the bounds of the frame of the new label is not contained in another label already added. You can use subviews property of the parent view to see all the views currently added.

Comment: @JozemiteApps Thanks for your comment, let me check this.

Comment: I asked something similar a time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593466/how-to-calculate-a-random-cgpoint-which-does-not-touch-a-uiview

Comment: @JozemiteApps Hey, Before adding to uiview I checked that it is intersect another label or not, it is working fine, now label is not overlapping. but if there is more number of keywords than it is not find position which is not intersect, so app is crash. any solution of this?